# как к кнопке добавить событие клавиатуры кнопки например 'a'?

Tags: javascript, html

Как добавить чтобы она еще с клавиатуры нажималась буквой "a" , а не только click ?

```html
<button id="button">кнопка</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

За это отвечает параметр [`accesskey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B/accesskey) указанная в параметре клавиша работает в паре с `alt`

```html
<button id="button" accesskey="q" onclick="console.log(this.textContent)">Alt + q</button>
<button id="button" accesskey="w" onclick="console.log(this.textContent)">Alt + w</button>
<br><br>
нажмите сюда чтобы страница получила фокус, такой способ специфичен к языку ввода
```

---

Вот вариант где вешаются слушатели на страницу:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button[key]').forEach(b => {
  let key = b.getAttribute('key');
  document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => 
        (e.key === key || e.key === key.toUpperCase()) && b.click());
})
```

```html
<button id="button" key="q" onclick="console.log(this.textContent)">q</button>
<button id="button" key="w" onclick="console.log(this.textContent)"> w</button>
<br><br>
нажмите сюда чтобы страница получила фокус
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: @recile всегда пожалуйста

Comment: минус данного способа в том, что *[Активация элементов с помощью Accesskey зависит от браузера и платформы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B/accesskey)*

Comment: @Alex так точно, а еще некоторые хоткеи могут быть заняты системой

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да, я к тому, что не сразу понятно, что нужно использовать разную комбинацию клавиш в разных браузерах и платформах, например в chrome alt+q, а в firefox уже Alt+ Shift+key и т.п.

Answer (score 2):

```js
/*проверять можно по event.key == 'a' или event.keyCode == 65 */
document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  if (event.keyCode == 65) {
    document.getElementById("button").click();
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="button" onclick="console.log('кнопка нажата')">кнопка</button>
<br/><br/>нажмите сюда, чтобы страница получила фокус
```